# Alternates for Include and Require PHP

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm using [Sensio Insights](https://insight.sensiolabs.com) for detecting errors in my architecture.

I have a basic template class that uses the output buffer to render the output of my template.

```
private function output() {
    if (is_readable($this->file)):
        extract($this->data);
        ob_start();
        require $this->file;
        $output = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();

        return $output;
    else:
        trigger_error('Error: Could not load template ' . $this->file . '!');
    endif;
}
```

Insights is throwing the obligatory:

> Using include() or require() bypasses lazy-loading of third-party
>   classes. Prefer using autoloading.

These files aren't classes, they can't be autoloaded.

Should I simply ignore these errors, or is there an autoloading type environment I can set up to lazy-load non-class files?

I read through the composer docs, and it states that you can only use the files autoloader for files you want to load on every execution, like utility functions and such.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide your file structure? Where are the files located, names etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should you ignore the errors? It depends.

Yes, you have to ignore them if you don't want to change the code of your template rendering class. That warning is a generic one that should inform you about using a function that isn't needed if you can use autoloading instead (with the minor omission that an autoloading function would trigger the exact same error - but autoloading is usually done by Composer now, and doesn't belong into your own codebase).

No, you should not ignore the error if you are interested in making a better, more testable codebase. You are doing some horrible things in that code when it comes to testing - you cannot really test that function and it's side effects correctly:

1. You are executing PHP code to render your template. While there is nothing wrong with it in general (PHP was built as a template engine), the function doesn't really deal with PHP errors that might occur - it assumes the code will execute just fine.
2. Error handling done by `trigger_error()` also cannot really be tested in an easy way. A better way to inform an object oriented program about errors would be to throw an exception.

So if you are using the static code analysis of Sensio "to detect errors in your architecture", I'd say that it has found something opinionated in your code.

You can leave it as it is and argue that this is a performant way of doing template rendering (and it probably really is). You can also argue that it's doing way too much with low level functions, directly hitting bare metal instead of abstracting away things, and try to get rid of it (there are plenty of very nice template engines around).

What you cannot do: Change this spot into some kind of autoloading. You'd have to put your templates into classes and use them to be able to trigger autoloading.

Comment: I don't use PHPUnit testing so that's not really an issue. I've never really seen the point of writing php code to test php code.  How do I test the test code? I have some nice template options though, so thanks.